# Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided only when building yet not when developing

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am deploying a Gatsby site using mdx files. When I use `npm run develop`, my site works as expected. When I use `npm run build`, I encounter the following error:

`Variable "$slug" of required type "String!" was not provided.`

It points to my blog.js file (Url path: /templates/blog/) as the source of the error. After some imports, `blog.js` appears as follows:

```
export const query = graphql`
query (
  $slug: String!
) {
  mdx(
    fields: {
      slug: {
        eq: $slug
      }
    }
  ) {
    frontmatter {
      title
      details
      date(formatString: "LL")
      tags
    }
    body
  }
}`

export default function Blog(props) {
    return (...content...
    )
}
```

The relevant parts of my config file is as you would expect.

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: '...',
    author: '...'
  },

  plugins: [...,
    {resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name:'src',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`
      }
...
```

My `gatsby-node.js` is as follows:

```
/* pathing via node.js; for path.basename*/
const path = require('path')

/* node function that runs when node is created*/
module.exports.onCreateNode = ({node, actions}) => {
    const {createNodeField} = actions

    if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
        const slug = path.basename(node.fileAbsolutePath, '.mdx')

        createNodeField({
            node,
            name: 'slug',
            value: slug
        })
    }
}

// Creating blog pages
// 1.Get path to template
// 2.Get markdown data
// 3.create new pages

module.exports.createPages = async ({graphql, actions}) => {
    const{ createPage } = actions
    const blogTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog.js')
    const res = await graphql(`
    query {
        allMdx {
            edges {
                node {
                    fields {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    `)
    
    res.data.allMdx.edges.forEach((edge) => {
        createPage({
            component: blogTemplate,
            path: `/blog/${edge.node.fields.slug}`,
            context: {
                slug: edge.node.fields.slug
            }
        })
    })

}
```

I'm quite perplexed, as I can open graphQL and find exactly what I would expect at each stage. What am I doing wrong for the build process to fail yet develop process to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd issue, and it would need a careful debug to know what is happening.

My guess is that in some post, the `slug` is not properly defined, so it's not matching the `String!` condition, which means that the `slug` will be a string (everything ok until here) but non-nullable (because of the exclamation mark, `!`. Further reference [here](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields)) so it's breaking your GraphQL query.

Try using it as a nullable field:

```
export const query = graphql`
query (
  $slug: String
) {
  mdx(
    fields: {
      slug: {
        eq: $slug
      }
    }
  ) {
    frontmatter {
      title
      details
      date(formatString: "LL")
      tags
    }
    body
  }
}`
```

Your `gatsby-node.js` looks good so far.

As I mentioned, the ideal solution would be debugging each post to know if there's any invalid `slug` (adding a debugger or a `console.log` and checking its values in the terminal's console).